# BIOS update or System Factory Restore - Lenovo ThinkPad x1 Carbon 5th

Tags: linux, boot, bios, uefi, thinkpad

I have erased my OS and now I can't manage to install other system or update the BIOS.

- Windows 7 I tries a couple of images but it doesn't even boots.
- Windows 10 enters in the installation mode but fails when is installing the bootloader.

Linux

- I can boot and use live images (majaro, ubuntu, linux mint) but the installation fails when configuring bootloader.

Manjaro

1. 16.6
2. 16.10
3. 17.1

Ubuntu

1. 16.04
2. 18.04 & 18.10
3. 19.04

Other things I did:

- Use the Lenovo update bios images: [support page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-20hr-20hq/20hr/20hr006bri/pf0xg2bx/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI) - tried on an ubuntu live image with no results (windows 10 to be tried after system restore)
- Set in Bios the support for UEFI and Legacy OS
- Clear the Bios security keys

---

- Bios version: `N1MET37W (1.22)`
- Release date: `07/04/2017`

Any help appreciated!

Comment: @John You've received one downvote, it's not the end of the world. I think it was because you didn't offer any real solution, just a workaround.

Comment: @Mihai, What errors do you get exactly? (By the way, please note that there's no such thing as Ubuntu 16, 18 or 19. The second part of the number is just as important. For example Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 are two completely different versions with different support policies.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will post here a anwser with the exact steps that I did in order to restore my system.

- Went to [lenovorecovery](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ro/en/lenovorecovery) page
- Download the `Lenovo USB Recovery Creator tool` for my device serial number
- Follow the steps on this video on [Creating a Recovery USB Key with Digital Download Recovery Service](https://support.lenovo.com/ro/en/videos/vid500094)

  - First step download the recovery image
  - Second step is to select the USB (16GB) to write the image
- Go to Bios -> Secure Boot -> Select `Clear all keys`
- Go to Bios -> `Restore system defaults`
- Restart and boot from Recovery USB
- There will be a screen that will start the recovery (~30min) - do not interrupt the process
- Then a popup will show up with the message `Recovery is done. Please remove the media.`
- **Attention** remove the media and leave the system to continue without intervene. The laptop will restart several times (~ 1.5h).
- In the end the system will start configuration steps (user, apps, etc)
- Done

---

After system restore **update BIOS**

- download and run Lenovo update BIOS utility: [support page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-20hr-20hq/20hr/20hr006bri/pf0xg2bx/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI)

New version: `LENOVO N1MET59W (1.44 ), 25.11.2019`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.